# NSOperation versus Asynchronous NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have an iPad app that runs a regular server sync process - it runs every 10 seconds or so.  The sync process downloads records that are inserted into a CoreData SQL-based store.  On occasion the number of records being handled can run into the hundreds or thousands.

The current sync process is based upon an `Asynchronous NSURLConnection` triggered by the main thread.  Once all `NSData` has been gathered by the `async` call then the main thread fires an `NSOperation` in the background to parse the `NSData` and insert it into the db.

So, the `NSURLConnection` is running asynchronously, and the db insert is running in a background `NSOperation`.  However, the orchestration of the `NSURLConnection` and the `NSOperation` is done in the main thread.  Given that there are large quantities of data being downloaded then I'm thinking that even this small amount of orchestration on the main thread may be impacting my UI responsiveness.

So, I'm thinking of refactoring the code into a single background `NSOperation` and making the `NSURLConnection` into a synchronous call.  A single `NSOperation` would then synchronously download the `NSData` and manage the db inserts.

Before I embark on quite a major refactoring I would be interested in people's views on whether this is a good decision.

With the current mechanism I notice some occasional hesitation in the UI. By placing the entire mechanism in a background `NSOperation` I am hoping that the UI will remain responsive.

Any words of wisdom would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend switching to a synchronous connection. Asynchronous connection uses less memory and gives you more control over the download process. To avoid UI freeze, I would try to force background processing only inside `NSURLConnection` delegate methods, like so:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        [self.mutableData appendData:data];
    });
}
```

EDIT:
As @jrturton stated in comments, you can specify the queue for `NSURLConnection` delegate methods. Use [setDelegateQueue:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/setDelegateQueue%3a) method (iOS 5.0+).

Comment: You can specify the queue on which NSURLConnection delegate methods are processed, this code is not necessary.